# Unable to get cron to append output from wget

Tags: bash, cron, wget

I have a cronjob setup and running, but the logfile keeps getting overwritten every time it runs. I would like for the wget output to be appended each time the cron runs.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
0 0 * * * wget url/script.php -O - >> /home/user/app/logs/logfile
```

Comment: `wget url/script.php -O - | tee -a logfile >/dev/null` maybe?

Comment: There must be something else happening here. `wget http://localhost/ -O - >> foo` correctly appends to the file for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
man wget
-a logfile
       --append-output=logfile
           Append to logfile.  This is the same as -o, only it appends to
           logfile instead of overwriting the old log file.  If logfile does
           not exist, a new file is created.
```

Try with this one scheme.

Comment: `-o` != `-O`.  One is appending the log data, and the other is appending the payload.

Comment: -O - should be outputting the wget response to stdout. From there, I would think >> should be responsible for actually appending data. I shouldn't need to care if wget output is appending or not if >> is supposed to be append whatever output it sent to it, right?